# SnakeYaml get stacked keys

Tags: java, dictionary, yaml, snakeyaml

When this is my .yml file:

```
test1: "string1"
test2:
  test3: "string2"
```

How do I get the value of `test3`?

```java
Map<String, Object> yamlFile = new Yaml().load(YamlFileInputStream);

yamlFile.get("test1"); // output: string1
yamlFile.get("test2"); // output: {test3=string2}

yamlFile.get("test2.test3"); // output: key not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML does not have *„stacked keys“*. It has nested mappings. The dot `.` is not a special character and can occur normally in a key, therefore you cannot use it for querying values in nested mappings.

You already show how to access the mapping containing the `test3` key, you can simply query the value from there:

```
((Map<String, Object>)yamlFile.get("test2")).get("test3");
```

However, it is much simpler to define the structure of your YAML file as class:

```java
class YamlFile {
    static class Inner {
        public String test3;
    }

    public String test1;
    public Inner test2;
}
```

Then you can load it like this:

```java
YamlFile file = new Yaml(new Constructor(YamlFile.class)).loadAs(
    input, YamlFile.class);
file.test2.test3; // this is your string
```