# Reading nested elements of a yaml file in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to access values from a yaml file in my java code.. WHat i am trying to achieve is that given a certain key i can lookup its value. I am able to correctly read in the yaml file in the code how ever the result i get back is of a linkedHashMap type, making it difficult to work with. I am unable to access a certain value  by using a key.

Here is my yaml file.

```
people:  
 men: 
  waiter:
   name: James
   age: 21
  airHost:
   name: John
   age: 33
 headmaster:
   name: Jake
   age: 38
women:
  waitress:
   name: Jane
   age: 21
  airHostess:
   name: Amy
   age: 33
 headmisstress:
   name: Eve
   age: 38
```

So lets say i want to read in the name for a waiter? i would need to access nested objects of people>men>waiter>name

here is my java code to read the yaml

```
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
  Reader yamlFile = new FileReader("src/main/resources/file.yml");
  Map<String , Object> yamlMaps = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(yamlFile);
```

Comment: You tagged the question with `jackson`, but use the SnakeYAML API. Please clarify which API you want to use. Also, is the structure of the YAML fixed (i.e. will the top mapping always contain `people`, which in turn always contains `men` and `women` etc) or can it contain arbitrarily structured data?

Comment: Thanks, i have edit the question. yes the structure is fixed. top level will always be people-->men and women etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SnakeYaml get stacked keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135911/snakeyaml-get-stacked-keys)

Comment: What all the keys you are interested in searching for and expected results? Is it only by name and age?

Comment: The link above does help a bit, how ever using that i am only able to access the second nested object, not deeper down. @dassum correct it is by name and age.so given people,name,watier, i should return the age and name

Comment: Well you need to apply the linked question to your structure. You just need to use another custom class instead of the `String` at the second level, and so on.

Comment: Ye i am trying to do that...  This is what i have  ((Map<String, Map<String,Object>>) yamlFiles.get("people")).get("people").get("waiter");    it seems very messy though, cant really see how to clean this up

Comment: Why don't you define a class as suggested in that answer

Comment: Thanks, I have done so and now understand how it works